# No-show or Non-show

Tags: expressions, vocabulary, common-word

Which phrase is correct ? This is the typical phrase we use for example when a passenger don't go to his flight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No-show," as that is common usage. Here is an easily looked-up [Lexico definition](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/no-show):

> "A person who has made a reservation, booking, or appointment but neither keeps nor cancels it."

Comment: It sounds also more familiar the "No-show" but I have seen also the "Non-Show" which is heard tragic.